# Primefaces - Add a textfield dynamically below the checkbox, if the checkbox is selected

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

In Primefaces (JSF), I have a list of checkboxes. (Data for the list comes dynamically from DB)

And I want to add a text field below the checkbox if the user ticks the checkbox.

Any hints please, how this can be done?

**HTML**

```
    <p:column>
        <p:selectManyCheckbox id="resolutionPower" value="#{resBRRD_83_2_3_Bean.selectedResolutionPowers_DD}" layout="grid" columns="1" required="true">
            <f:selectItems value="#{resBRRD_83_2_3_Bean.resolutionPowers_DD}" var="data" itemValue="#{data}" itemLabel="#{data.tcdDesc}" />
            <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{resBRRD_83_2_3_Bean.resolutionPowers_DD}" />
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
        <p:inputText />
    </p:column>
```

[image]

Comment: did you try an ajax event and a rendred an inputText ?!?

Comment: and your hidden inputText it will be between list elements (let say for exemple between `1. THe sale ...` and `2. The Bridge in ...` ) ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight Thanks mate, I managed to do it using ui:repeat

Comment: waiting for your answer and if it's a good one maybe you will have an upvote ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it as below, using ui:repeat  with separate fields

**HTML**

```
<ui:repeat var="gtField" value="#{resBRRD_83_2_3_Bean.resolutionPowers_DD}">
    <h:panelGroup id="resolutionPower">
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox itemLabel="#{gtField.tcdDesc}" value="#{gtField.selected}">
            <p:ajax type="change" process="@this" update="@this resolutionPower" />
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <br />
        <p:inputText rendered="#{gtField.selected}" style="width:100%" />
        <p:spacer height="5px" rendered="#{gtField.selected}" />
        <br />
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

After the above fix,

[image]